# How to transform this T-SQL into lambda expression (Group and Sum)

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

For God's sake someone help me ... I spent all the morning trying to learn linq and lambda expressions, but I still can't get what I need.

I have this query:

```
select IDHOLDINGGRUPO, IDUNIDADE, IDOPERADORA, ANOPROC, MESPROC, DATACONHECIMENTO, TIPO, sum(VALOR) as TOTAL
from VIEW_EVENTOS_ATENDIMENTOS
group by IDHOLDINGGRUPO, IDUNIDADE, IDOPERADORA, ANOPROC, MESPROC, DATACONHECIMENTO, TIPO
```

Which returns me this result:

```
IDHOLDING IDUNIDADE IDOPERADORA ANOPROC MESPROC DATACONHECIMENTO TIPO TOTAL
1           1           1        2001       1       2001-01-01     A   150.00
1           2           1        2001       1       2001-01-01     A   300.00
```

I'm trying to get the same result with a lambda expression. Something like:

```
var Resultado = lista
                  .GroupBy(x => new { x.HoldingGrupoDto.Id, Id2 = x.UnidadeDto.Id, Id3 = x.OperadoraDto.Id, x.DataConhecimento, x.AnoProc, x.MesProc })
                  .Select(group => group.Sum(item => item.Valor)).FirstOrDefault() ?? default(double);
```

But this only returns the sum column. How to get all columns, exactly the same, to the example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your projection (`.Select`) is in correct. You should add extra properties to the object:

```
var Resultado = lista.GroupBy(x => new { Id1 = x.HoldingGrupoDto.Id, Id2 = x.UnidadeDto.Id, Id3 = x.OperadoraDto.Id, x.DataConhecimento, x.AnoProc, x.MesProc })
                     .Select(group => new {
                         Key = group.Key,
                         Valor = group.Sum(item => item.Valor)
                     }).FirstOrDefault();
```

A better way to write it would be:

```
var Resultado = lista.GroupBy(key => new { Id1 = key.HoldingGrupoDto.Id, Id2 = key.UnidadeDto.Id, Id3 = key.OperadoraDto.Id, key.DataConhecimento, key.AnoProc, key.MesProc },
                              item => item.Valor)
                     .Select(g => new {
                          g.Id1,
                          g.Id2,
                          g.Id3,
                          g.DataConhecimento, 
                          g.AnoProc, 
                          g.MesProc,
                          Valor = g.Sum()
                     }).FirstOrDefault();
```

But IMO looks cleaner to use query syntax in this case:

```
var resultAdo = from x in lista
                group x.Valor by new { Id1 = x.HoldingGrupoDto.Id, Id2 = x.UnidadeDto.Id, Id3 = x.OperadoraDto.Id, x.DataConhecimento, x.AnoProc, x.MesProc } into g
                select new {
                    g.Id1,
                    g.Id2,
                    g.Id3,
                    g.DataConhecimento, 
                    g.AnoProc, 
                    g.MesProc,
                    Valor = g.Sum()
                };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include all the Columns you need into your `.Select` like this:

```
...
    .Select(group => new {group.Id, group.Id2, SumValor = group.Sum(item => item.Valor), ...})
...
```